# sign determinant $2\times 2$

Tags: linear-algebra, determinant, vectors

I have been reading internet and tried to understand the explanation of the sign of a determinant of a $2\times 2$ matrix.

if I have a matrix

\begin{array}{cc}
    a & b \\
    c & d\\
   \end{array}

the determinant is : a*d-c*b. I read on the wikipedia that if the angle between the first and second vector turns in clockwise direction, it is negative. 
this is my example:

[image]

i want the angle that i draw. I have calculated the 2 vectors:

```
vect1=(-28, 1)
vect2=(7, 102)
```

and the det(vect2, vect1) I have positive. I don't understand why it is positive while the angle turns in clockwise direction.

Can someone explain me what the sign of the determinant means really?

Comment: Hint: The determinant of a $2\times 2$ matrix is equal to the $z$ component of the cross product of the two columns in 3D.

Comment: Your figure is wrong. The second vector should be pointing upward.

Comment: @user72694 actually it's not wrong because the origin (0.0) is in the left up corner.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Graphing your vectors on  Wolfram Alpha

[image]

you'll see that you've graphed the second vector incorrectly. Using the image here, you'll see that the angle from vector $2$ to vector $1$ is indeed counter-clockwise, and so the value of the determinant you computed should be positive.

Otherwise, if you need for the second vector to point downward, then you should use $[7, -102]$, which will then yield a determinant that is negative.

**Remark**: If this question arose in the context of a computing environment, then the usual "rules" that apply to the Cartesian Coordinate system (or here, in what applies for the sign of the determinant of two vectors in $\mathbb R^2$) *will not* apply when the y-axis is taken to be at the *top* (of the screen), such that numbers become increasingly large as you descend to the bottom of the screen. In this context, a clockwise rotation from vector $2$ to vector $1$ should be positive.